# Animating terrain as its modeled

Tags: modeling, animation, texturing

Is there a way to animate a terrain as it is being modeled? As in have a hill rise up from a plane. Also is this possible with the terrain having a texture to it?
How would I go about this?

Comment: what kind of texture you want?
There are procedural ways to apply color by elevation, by normal...

Comment: If you're hand modeling your terrain, you can generate new shapekeys as you're going.

Answer (score 2):

You can use animated shape keys for it. To avoid too much stretching of the texture, you can use object coordinate.Like this:
[image]